# Same Plugin tables between wordpress installations

Tags: plugins, database

I know that you can install two wordpress sites in the same database.
However, what I am trying to achieve is that after doing that, specific plugins (that are common between the two websites) use the same tables.
Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to know without inspecting the plugin itself on a case by case basis.

Doing this requires a unique answer for every specific plugin. There is no general answer that works for all or even some WordPress plugin tables. Every plugin is unique and will have a different answer, some will be a No, some will be a Yes.

**Only the authors of the specific plugin can answer this, you need to ask the other users or support routes for the plugin you have in mind.** Depending on the plugin it may be impossible, there is no way to know in advance, there is no catch all general answer.

WordPress does not provide general APIs for custom tables that would allow this.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. I thought as much.